# HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found, on window server 2012 with 2.0 application pool

Tags: asp.net-2.0, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a 2.0 .Net framework application which I moved to windows server 2012 with the same application pool setting of v2.0 and integrated mode. For some reason it throws HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found error. I have followed https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019689 and it does not work yet.

Also see my web.config as per the above page setting:

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have .NET 3.5 installed on the server.  For some strange reason, I believe 3.5 handles all previous versions of .NET as well.  I've seen cases where even if you have 2.0 installed and are running a 2.0 pool, you still need 3.5 installed.

Comment: Yes, I have .Net 3.5 installed on the server. but still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (with a .net 4 webapp).
In the past you could resolve this with a aspnet_regiis command.
In Windows server you can resolve this by uninstalling asp.net [your version]. and the re-installing the same version.

This will reregister the correct IIS mappings

You can access these settings in the Server Manager [image: Add/remove roles and features]